# why is it invalid?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
ALTER TABLE MAJEST_ORDERS( 
ADD CONSTRAINT PMT_STATUS CHECK (PAYMENT_STATUS ="1" OR PAYMENT_STATUS = "0"));
```

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
>   01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals. (integer literals need no quotes at all.)

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses don't look right.  Also, constants should be in single quotes for strings and dates:

```
ALTER TABLE MAJEST_ORDERS
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_PMT_STATUS CHECK (PAYMENT_STATUS IN (0, 1));
```

Use single quotes if the value is a string:

```
ALTER TABLE MAJEST_ORDERS
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_PMT_STATUS CHECK (PAYMENT_STATUS IN ('0', '1'));
```

Comment: Use double quotes for schema object names (such as table or column names).